# Swift programmatically-added constraints dont work

Tags: swift, uikit, constraints, programmatically-created

I have a view inside a scrollview:

[image]

Now I want to add the child views to that view programmatically. Thats my code to do that:

1. Child view (works)

   ```
   //Adds header to the view again because it was removed in the clear() method
   //Header is just a label
   lv.addSubview(header)
   header.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.superview!.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
   header.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.superview!.topAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
   header.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.superview!.widthAnchor).isActive = true
   header.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: MainTabViewController.fontSize*3).isActive = true //Just a constant
   ```

Now I execute this code repeatedly:

```
private func makeTextLabel(text: NSAttributedString, bgColor: UIColor?, maxWidth: CGFloat?) -> UILabel {
    //Creates label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    lv.addSubview(label)
    //Adjustments
    if(bgColor != nil) {
        label.backgroundColor = bgColor
    }
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.attributedText = text
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    let width = maxWidth ?? lv.frame.size.width-8
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightForLabel(attributedText: label.attributedText, width: width)).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lv.leadingAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    let previousView = lv.subviews[lv.subviews.count-1]
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousView.bottomAnchor, constant:  10).isActive = true
    return label
}
```

All the labels are added, but the constraints dont work at all. Here is what is looks like (when I execute the method above 2 times):

[image]

EDIT: The main problem is solved. I am using a StackView now.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/59828434/6257435)

I now want my labels to have an offset to the edges, so I use those lines:

```
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lessonStackView.leadingAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lessonStackView.trailingAnchor, constant: -offset).isActive = true
```

But as the StackView seems to set x-constraints itself, I get this warning:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "UILabel:0x7f9c16c22c30'Falls dir die App gef\U00e4llt...'   (active, names: '|':JavaProf.MultipleContentsView:0x7f9c19024a60 )>",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `width` anchor. You should not care about width (and you don't really know it), use `trailingAnchor` instead:

```
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lv.trailingAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
```

Remove `heightAnchor`, instead let system calculate the height for you:

```
label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
```

That should be all needed.

However, as a side note, instead of creating a constraint to previous label, you could just use a `UIStackView`.

Comment: I am using a StackView now. I updated my question, it would be great, if you took another look at it!

Comment: If you want offsets from the edges, just offset the whole stack view. That's the easiest method.

Comment: Thanks, but the offset depends on the different labels, so I can't do that in this case

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `UIStackView` for a stack of labels (or other views) and you want them to have different leading spacing, you have a couple options:

1) Embed the label in a `UIView`. Let the `UIView` fill the width of the stack view, and give the contained label constraints to the view.

2) Set the stack view `Aligment` to `Trailing`. Then add a width constraint to each label, equal to the width of the stack view. For a label you want to have, say, a 32-point "left margin," set the constant on that label to `-32`.

Here is a quick example:

```
class LeftMarginViewController: UIViewController {
    let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .trailing
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for i in 1...7 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.numberOfLines = 0
            if i == 5 {
                v.text = "Label 5 has a lot of text to demonstrate what happens when it needs to wrap onto multiple lines."
            } else {
                v.text = "Label \(i)"
            }
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(v)
            switch i {
            case 6:
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -32.0).isActive = true
            case 2, 4, 5:
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
            default:
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            }
        }

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])

    }
}
```

Stack view has `Alignment: Trailing`, each label has width equal to stack view width, labels 2, 4 and 5 have `constant = -16` and label 6 has `constant = -32`.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not use exactly this approach, but I changed the alignment of my StackView to center instead of fill. Now the warning is gone and everything is working fine