# How can I get the actual height of my content view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a UIView that contains a UIScrollView, and that UIScrollView contains another UIView, which contains labels etc. Sometimes, certain labels contain 3 lines of text, sometimes they contain 15,... depending on the received data. The view also changes when certain buttons get clicked. When I scroll through my screen, it doesn't go al the way to the bottom. I notice that the height of the labels in label.frame.height is way smaller than the actual height of the label. How can I get the actual size of the labels at runtime?
Anyone that can help?

I've tried overriding function viewDidLayoutSubviews:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        contentview.layoutSubviews()
        
        var contentHeigt: CGFloat = 0
        for subview in contentview.subviews{
            contentHeigt += subview.frame.height
        }
                
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentHeigt)
    }
```

but that's where the height doesn't seem to match the actual height.

I've tried this:

```
func getLableHeightRuntime(label:UILabel) -> CGFloat {
            let stringValue = label.text!
            let width:CGFloat = 0
            let height:CGFloat = 0
            let font = UIFont(name: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17).fontName, size: 17)
            let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
            let boundingBox = stringValue.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
            return ceil(boundingBox.height)
        }
```

seems to give back the right size, but when I add that to the contentHeight in viewDidLayoutSubviews, like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        contentview.layoutSubviews()
        
        var contentHeigt: CGFloat = 0
        for subview in contentview.subviews{
            contentHeigt += subview.frame.size.height
        }
        
        contentHeigt += getLableHeightRuntime(label: lblLocations)
        contentHeigt += getLableHeightRuntime(label: lblTeachers)
        
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width, height: contentHeigt)
    }
```

I can't click certain buttons, and it scrolls way too far.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout / constraints on the subviews of your "contentView"?

Comment: I have a ton of constraints on my subviews. Constrained to other labels, or to the superview

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto-layout / constraints, you don't need to set the scroll view's `.contentSize` -- auto-layout handles that for you.

Quick example:

```
class ContentSizeExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()

    // we'll set the text of this label to the
    //  scrollView's .contentSize
    //  determined by auto-layout
    let centerLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        // create a "content view"
        let contentView = UIView()
        
        // let's create Top-Left, Center and Bottom-Right labels
        let topLeftLabel = UILabel()
        topLeftLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        topLeftLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        topLeftLabel.text = "Top-Left"
        
        centerLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        centerLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        centerLabel.text = "Center"
        
        let bottomRightLabel = UILabel()
        bottomRightLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        bottomRightLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        bottomRightLabel.text = "Bottom-Right"
        
        // we'll be using auto-layout / constraints
        [topLeftLabel, centerLabel, bottomRightLabel, contentView, scrollView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        // add the labels to the content view
        contentView.addSubview(topLeftLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(centerLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(bottomRightLabel)
        
        // add the content view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        
        // add the scroll view to the view
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let cg = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // inset the scroll view 20-points on all 4 sides
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            // constrain Top-Left label top/leading to content view
            //  with 8-points "padding"
            topLeftLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLeftLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            // constrain Bottom-Right label trailing/bottom to content view
            //  with 8-points "padding"
            bottomRightLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            bottomRightLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain Bottom-Right label
            //  400-points to the right
            //  800-points below
            // of the Top-Left label
            bottomRightLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 400.0),
            bottomRightLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLeftLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 800.0),

            // constrain Center label to center of content view
            centerLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            centerLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),

            // constrain all 4 sides of content view Content Layout Guide
            //  with 8-points "padding"
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cg.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

        ])
        
        // so we can see the framing
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        contentView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        centerLabel.text = "ContentSize: \(scrollView.contentSize)"
    }
    
}
```

It will look like this - scroll view background is Red, "content view" background is Blue, labels are constrained relative to `contentView` and `contentView` is constrained to the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`.

The "center label" text is set in `viewDidAppear()` - which is when we know everything has been laid-out:

[image]

scrolled toward the middle:

[image]

and all the way to bottom-right:

[image]

If/when the subviews change (multi-line labels change text, positions/sizes of views are changed via code, etc), as long as you have your constraints setup correctly, you never need to set `.contentSize`.

Comment: I set the constraints on the storyboard, does this also work, or do I need to set them programatically?

Comment: @Nienke - sure, as long as you have your constraints setup correctly. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59828434/6257435

Comment: Thank you for the link, I followed the "tutorial", but now I can't scroll at all anymore, I'm assuming somethings wrong with my constraints, but I can't seem to figure out what it is

Comment: @Nienke - if you create a [mre] -- strip your current stuff down to just what's needed to check out the scroll view -- and post it somewhere like GitHub we can talk a look at it to figure out what's not-quite-right.